# How to invoke packaged function in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a package specification and body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack_debt AS
  overdue_charge CONSTANT number :=0.005;
  FUNCTION debt (person_nr IN number) RETURN number;
end pack_debt;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_debt AS
  FUNCTION debt (person_nr IN number)
    RETURN number IS
    overdue number;
  BEGIN
    select (date_of_return-hiredate)*(price*overdue_charge) into overdue 
      from books, rentals, users  
     where users.id = rentals.user_id 
       and books.id = rentals.book_id 
       and date_of_return - hiredate > 14 
       and users.id = person_nr;
  end debt;
end pack_debt;
```

I want to see the values of overdue, but when I try to invoke the function it doesn't work. How should it be invoked ?

If I just create  the function:

```
create or replace function dept (person_nr IN number)
  RETURN number IS
  overdue number;
begin
  select (date_of_return - hiredate) * (price * 0.005) into overdue 
    from books, rentals, users 
   where users.id = rentals.user_id 
     and books.id = rentals.book_id 
     and date_of_return - hiredate > 14 
     and users.id = person_nr;
  RETURN (overdue);
end dept;
```

and do..

```
select dept('1') from dual;
```

I get the values of overdue. How can I get same thing when using packages?

Comment: Are you sure your package compiled without error? The function in it doesn't have a RETURN statement. How were you calling the function when it didn't work? P.S. I cannot over-emphasise how important whitespace is... please use more of it. It makes your code so much more readable.

Comment: Yes, both packages were created. So
    RETURN number IS overdue number; 
is not enough?

Comment: No, and your package won't have been created without an error... you need the RETURN statement as you have in your stand-alone function `return overdue;`. After compiling the package type `show error`, and you should get some.

Answer (score 0):

`FUNCTION` block syntax is pretty same, when both written stand alone or encapsulated inside a Package.
As @Ben says, a `RETURN` statement is mandatory.

You declare the `FUNCTION` , just as `RETURN NUMBER`, but didn't specify the variable or constant that the function returns, so it's incomplete! And your Package Body is left `INVALID`.

And finally calling it is pretty simple,

```
SELECT pack_debt.debt('1') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the code. i think it should work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack_debt AS
      overdue_charge CONSTANT number :=0.005;
      FUNCTION debt (person_nr IN number) RETURN number;
    end pack_debt;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_debt AS
      FUNCTION debt (person_nr IN number)
        RETURN number AS
        overdue number;
      BEGIN
        select SALARY into overdue from avrajit
    where SR_NO = person_nr;
    RETURN overdue;
      end debt;
    end pack_debt;
    ------------------------------------
    DECLARE
    AV_NO NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    AV_NO:= pack_debt.debt(2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(AV_NO);
    END;
```